# set CheckColumn as checked programmatically

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am using 'CheckColumn' in 'gridpanel' and also I am using a window which contain a chart. In the window, when I click on some values in the chart, I have to set the corresponding check box as checked in the grid. My question is how to set a check box as checked programmatically? I got the row id of the corresponding value that I need but I do not know how to use it to check it.

Thanks a lot!

```
     // in the code below, i am searching for the specific row how contain my value 
grids.getStore().each(function(rec){  
                    var rowData = rec.data; 
                    if (rowData['value']==value)
                   {  
                   var record = grids.getStore().getAt(rec.index);

                   // what i can do now? // thanks  

                   }
                });
```

Comment: Where can i find the methods that i can use with getStore() ? anyone can help me with that? thanks.

Comment: i found what i need , just: add rec.set('myfield', true); 

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found what i need , just: add

```
rec.set('myfield', true);
```

thanks